# Is it expensive to call D3.js transition multiple times during scroll?

Tags: d3.js

I have a scroll event listener that triggers a D3.js transition when the page hits a specific scroll target. The animation works nicely and doesn't lag, but the transition is called on each scroll position. Is this expensive? After the first `draw()` the `#mySvgShape` is set to `fill-opacity:0.8`. Is it an issue to keep calling the transition during the scroll?

`scrollPosition` is the percentage (0 to 1) of the page that has been scrolled.

```
    function draw(scrollPosition) {
      if (scrollPosition > 0.2 && scrollPosition < 0.4) {
        el.select('#mySvgShape')
        .transition()
        .style("fill-opacity", "0.8");
      }else{
        el.select('#mySvgShape')
        .transition()
        .style("fill-opacity", "1e-6");
      }
```

Comment: Check the element's opacity before calling the transition.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks, Gerardo.

Comment: No worries. The default duration is 250ms. So, an even better approach is to check if there is any active transition.

Comment: I understand how to check the value of fill-opacity with a getter, but how would I check if there's an active transition? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#active If you create a running version of your code it would be easier to show you how to check it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jmauro/egpy77j8/64/ If you want to submit a forked JSFiddle as the answer I'd certainly mark it as the accepted. Thank you! – jm22 45 mins ago

Comment: jm22, sorry for the 1 week late answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there is any transition happening and, if yes, do not call the transition again.

To do that, use [d3.active](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#active):

> *d3.active(node[, name])*:
>
> returns the active transition on the specified node with the specified name, if any.

So, your `if` can be changed to this:

```
if (percentage > 0.2 && percentage < 0.4) {
    if (!d3.active(d3.select("#dam-fill").node())) {
        d3.select("#dam-fill")
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .style("fill-opacity", "1")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-50, -200) scale(1.2,1.2)");
    }
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/ze2dc976/

I changed the transition to 5000 ms just to show that, if you scroll up or down while the transition is happening, it doesn't stop (as in your fiddle). Thus, not only calling transition multiple times in the scroll is expansive, it will mess the transition.